# Issues when restarting NiFi cluster

Tags: python, apache-nifi, ambari, hdf

I have Ambari 2.4.2 with the latest HDF installed. I mainly installed it to moderate my NiFi cluster. I have configured the NiFi to work with LDAP although I don't think there's any connection to it.

Now each time I try to restart the NiFi service on the cluster, on two of my nodes the Ambari script returns an error: "No JSON object could be decoded". 
It is related to the file "/usr/hdf/current/nifi/conf/config_version".

When I delete the file it obviously regenerates and the nodes work(after I restart it). But then when I try to restart the cluster again it returns the same error again and won't start the NiFi service on the node. It happens on the same nodes again and again.

Any thoughts?